# Rails: guest accounts and signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model

I have a user model that begins like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  has_secure_password if not_guest?
  geocoded_by :location
  after_validation :geocode
```

In the same model I define the method

```
def not_guest?
  guest == false
end
```

But like this I get the error: `undefined method not_guest? for #<Class:0x0000000598cb28>`

To me it is clearly defined in the same model as the erroneous call (i.e. the line `has_secure_password if not_guest?`). What is wrong with my method?

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing an instance of a User?

Stick a binding.pry before the invocation of the method and confirm the type.

Also, if you are in Rails production mode, you will need to restart for any changes made to your models.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure what you mean by an instance of a User in this context, since neither the has_secure_password line not the method it calls reference a specific user. I'm using byebug but I'm not sure what you are looking to verify.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the model, you can:

```
has_secure_password validations: true, unless: :new_guest?


def self.new_guest
 new { |u| u.guest = true }
end
```

You can also look into STI and Polymorphic Associations for creating two types of users (i.e. models/member.rb and models/guest.rb for STI).

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but it didn't make a difference. The error refers to the method being undefined, not some error within the method so I wasn't really expecting it to work. I still get the same error :/

Comment: Sorry, does this work, please see changes and let me now

Comment: No unfortunately, it seems that has_secure_password still runs even when I'm using a guest account... It's as if it's just ignoring the " unless: :new_guest?" part.